# How did Fire Lord Sozin seemingly bend (or even absorb) smoke?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

In Avatar the Last airbender, there is that episode where Avatar Roku was battling the volcano then FireLord sozin came to help.

He (FireLord Sozin) did this whirling thing with his hands and the poisonous gases seemed to enter through his fingers on one side and out the other hand - just like someone is redirecting lightning.

Lightning is understandable since it's energy, a force; but how does gases behave that way? What exactly is he doing there?

Check picture below:

[image]

Comment: I've always wondered this myself.  My assumption has always been that, since Firebenders are [really more like heat-benders](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/85421/20221), he was draining the heat from the air and then shooting it out in a concentrated form.  But it really does look like he's smoke-bending...  Looking forward to seeing if anyone has an answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### FireLord Sozin was not smoke bending, he was heat-bending. Note the volcano becoming quiescent and dark after he redirects the heat energy.

- The heat transfer starts around 3:30... the lava behind him grows dark and cool. All fire-bending is basically a mastery and control of heat energy. He is, in essence, fire-bending in reverse, taking the heat FROM a source rather than creating heat and then explosively releasing it as fire or flame bursts.

[image]

- In this case, I think this is what we call "creative representation." Imagine if Souzin had drawn the heat out of the lava and there was no representation. It would appear as if he were just posing there and the lava grew cool. Since it is supposed to be a show for younger audiences, they wanted to show SOMETHING was happening AND Souzin was responsible for it. Not an ideal representation but it was something nonetheless. I accept it and expect the betrayal afterward wiped the event from anyone's mind...

Comment: Heat bending? Never heard of that. Is it another subset of fire bending?

Comment: @Parto  Check out my answer [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/85421/20221) for a discussion of heat-bending.  The short answer: it isn't a subset of Firebending, it's what Firebending really is, in more specific terms.  That's why Firebenders don't need fire nearby in order to bend, but they *do* need a source of heat/warmth.

Comment: All firebending is basically a mastery and control of heat energy. He is in essence, fire-bending in reverse, taking the heat FROM a source rather than creating heat and then explosively releasing it as fire or flame bursts.

Comment: @Thaddeus I'm prepared to chalk it up to "inaccurate animation," but out of curiosity, do you have an explanation for the way that the steam seems be to absorbed into his hand?  Releasing steam makes sense, as he's pushing the heat out, but that clip REALLY looks like the smoke and gas itself from the volcano is being absorbed into his body.  Got a creative justification?

Comment: In this case, I think this is what we call "creative representation." Imagine if he had drawn the heat out of the lava and there was no representation. It would appear as if he were just posing there and the lava grew cool. Since it is supposed to be a show for younger audiences, they wanted to show SOMETHING was happening AND Souzin was responsible for it. Not an ideal representation but it was something nonetheless. I accept it and expect the betrayal afterward wiped the event from anyone's mind...

Comment: @Nerrolken I actually wanted to point that out, that smoke (am not sure anymore if it's actually smoke) seems to be absorbed into his hand, through the body and out the other hand. How do you explain that?

Comment: @Thaddeus  So it isn't steam *or* smoke, it's the animators' way of drawing the ambient heat.  I like it.  :)  And, come to think of it, if I were to draw a [heat haze](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirage#Heat_haze) in a cartoon, it would probably look a lot like that.

Comment: @Nerrolken Haha. cool then, cleared up.